# Inverse of $f(x)=2-\sqrt{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the inverse of $f(x)=2-\sqrt{x}$

The solution according to my book is $(2-x)^2$ whereas I arrived at $-(y-2)^2$. Here's how I arrived at that:

$y=2-\sqrt{x}$

$y-2=-\sqrt{x}$ # subtract 2 from both sides

$(y-2)^2=-x$ # square both sides so that x is no longer a radical

$x = -(y-2)^2$ # multiply both sides by -1 to get just x

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $(2-x)^2$?

Here's a screen shot of the question from the book in case I misunderstood it:
[image]

Comment: Try squaring $-\sqrt{x}$ again.

Comment: Hint: x is positive and see your third step is $(y-2)^2=-x$. Squaring in second step will remove -ve sign.

Comment: Also, $(y-2)^2=(2-y)^2$

Comment: I'm aware that a squared real number is always positive if that's what the hints are getting at. I considered that but got confused because I read it as 'take the negation of hat ever positive number you end up with'

Comment: @Doug Fir you did a mistake while going from second to third step

Comment: $(-\sqrt x)^2 = x$ not $-x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y=f(x)=2-\sqrt x,$

$\sqrt x=2-y$

$f^{-1}(y)=x=(2-y)^2$

$f^{-1}(x)=(2-x)^2=(x-2)^2$

Answer (score 1):

If $y=f(x)=2-\sqrt x$, interchange $x$ and $y$ and solve for $y$ to get $f^{-1}(x)$.

Get $x=2-\sqrt y\implies \sqrt y=2-x\implies f^{-1}(x)= y=(x-2)^2$.